# Question about deriving probabilities in the Tobit model

Tags: regression, tobit-regression

[image]

In the Tobit model: Why do you divide by σ when deriving the probability that y = 0? Is it something to do with the assumption that ε is distributed N(0,σ^2) and not N(0,1)? If this is the case why does dividing by σ standardise it?

Answer (score 0):

You’re correct - Dividing by $\sigma$ here makes it so that $\epsilon/\sigma\sim N(0,1)$.  So now $\phi$ is the cdf of a standard normal random variable.  Had the division not be made, it would be a normal random variable with variance $\sigma^2$.  Dividing by $\sigma$ standardizes it because if $X\sim N(0,\sigma^2), $ $$var(X/\sigma)=\frac{1}{\sigma^2}var(X)=\sigma^2/\sigma^2=1.$$